# Cannot get TiKz images side-by-side instead of up and down

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, captions

Here is what I have so far after reading a post on here saying subfigure is used to place images horizontally:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{node distance=2cm, auto}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}

\section{}

\begin{figure}
     \begin{subfigure}
          \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
          \caption*{(1)}
     \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}
          \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
          \caption*{(2)}
     \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}
          \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
          \caption*{(3)}
     \end{subfigure}
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But it still places the images vertically. I want to make my image look exactly like this:

[image]

Also the `\caption*` doesn't seem to be working, even though I read a post on here that said it would get rid of the word "FIGURE" in the caption, it doesn't in my case.

Comment: There are many different ways to arrange images side-by-side, including tabular, minipage and \makebox.  Captioning is more problematic if you want things like a list of figures or hyperlinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `subfigure` environment, from the [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package, requires as mandatory argument a length expressing the width reserved for the subfloat; notice the `%` characters after the first and second `\end{subfigure}` which suppress blank spaces that otherwise would push the third image down. Instead of your manual numbering I used `\caption{}` to get automatic numbering (in particular, allowing cross-referencing the objects):

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\tikzset{node distance=2cm, auto}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
     \begin{subfigure}{.3333\textwidth}
     \centering
          \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
     \caption{}
     \end{subfigure}%
     \begin{subfigure}{.3333\textwidth}
     \centering
          \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
          \caption{}
     \end{subfigure}%
     \begin{subfigure}{.3333\textwidth}
     \centering
          \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
          \caption{}
     \end{subfigure}
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want to manually give the width, the `subcaption` package offers `\subcaptionbox` (you manually add horizontal spacing if required between the subfloats):

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\tikzset{node distance=2cm, auto}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
     \subcaptionbox{}{%
          \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}}\qquad
     \subcaptionbox{}{%
          \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}}\qquad
     \subcaptionbox{}{%
          \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`amsart` defaults to small capitals for the subfloat numbering; to get lower case letters add

```
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelfont=rm}
```

after loading `subcaption`.